# How to group and process in the order of attribute using LINQ method syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a request table with the following schema:

**Request**

```
REQ_SOURCE(int), REQ_DATE (datetime), REQ_NAME (string)
```

I need to iterate through the requests per `REQ_SOURCE` in the order of the `REQ_DATE`. I.e The request source with the earliest request need to be evaluated first. Does the following code do that?

```
var requestSourceOrdered = requests
    .GroupBy(x => x.REQ_SOURCE)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Min(y => y.REQ_DATE))
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();

foreach(var requestSource in requestSourceOrdered) 
{
  //Process requestSource here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to only return the earliest request per request source. If what you want to do is to iterate all the requests, below code snippet should help.

```
var requestSourceOrdered = requests
       .GroupBy(x => x.REQ_SOURCE)
       .SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.REQ_DATE))
       .ToList()
```

Hope it helps!